# Using hash of access/refresh token as API Ids for managing tokens

Tags: security, rest, hash, oauth-2.0

We’re writing an API to manage OAuth2 clients that have access to our system, and the access/refresh tokens associated with them. We need an ID for each token, and it shouldn’t be the actual token itself. This ID will be used to refer to tokens (ie. *GET /clients/your-clientId/tokens/*).

The tokens are identified in the database with a hash (sha1) of the 122 bit token (it’s a random UUID).

Is it acceptable to expose these hashes as the identifiers for tokens, or should we add additional identifier for each token? The key space is sufficiently large that I feel like the hash should be sufficient, but I’m wondering what the best practice is here. Is it better to use something completely unrelated to the token in case there are ever any vulnerabilities found with the hash algorithm?

What hash algorithms are others using to store access and refresh tokens for their APIs?